# Не понимаю почему вывод не такой как я ожидаю (проверку при дебаге он просто проходит мимо и создает два объекта мапа с одинаковыми ключами)

Tags: java

```
  public class Solution1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader file = new FileReader(args[0]);
        TreeMap<String, Double> list = new TreeMap<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            String[] s = str.split("\\s");
            String name = s[0];
            Double count = Double.parseDouble(s[1]);
            list.put(name, count);
        }
        sc.close();
        file.close();
        list.forEach((a, b) -> System.out.println(a + " " + b));
    }
}
```

Comment: if (list.containsKey(name)) {
                    list.merge(name, list.get(name), (a, b) -> b + count);
                } else {
                    list.put(name, count);
                }

Comment: В IDEA чтобы опуститься в низкий уровень при дебаге - f7.